# Mixture of BCAA and Creatine

Tags: bodybuilding, workout, creatine, bcaa

Can I mix BCAA and creatine powder together and dissolve them into the water? Can I drink them together?

Should I choose creatine monohydrate or creatine complex? Which one is better for power enhancement?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since one thing wasn't addressed properly in the only answer so far: there's nothing against taking the two together, like, at all.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BCAAs are just three of the constituent amino acids of whole protein, so supplementing sufficient protein intake with BCAAs is just wasting money. Just eat more whole protein if you think you need more BCAAs (which you probably don’t). For reference, 25g of whey protein has about 5g of BCAAs, provides all the other essential amino acids, and generally costs less than a 5g scoop of BCAAs.

Creatine Monohydrate is the only creatine you should ever care about. No other form has ever been proven to be superior to Monohydrate, but *every* other form has been proven to be more expensive.

Comment: "BCAAs are just inferior protein" well no, they are essential amino acids. That they are, as a matter of fact, more than just covered in any protein rich diet (and thus simply superfluous as a supplement) is another matter. Protein = chains of 100+ amino acids. I fully agree with the gist and message of this answer though, so +1.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Right, my point is that a 25g scoop of whey has 5g of BCAAs in it, as well as all the other essential amino acids, and generally costs less than a scoop of BCAAs. I revised that statement a bit.

Comment: @Thomas Markov Thank you for the suggestion. In other words, I can mix BCAA and creatine monohydrate together and drink them together. Is it correct?

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Thank you very much for your suggestion.